# Number of likes for the FB post

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

In my app I wanna explicitly show number of likes for any particular post. Is there a API call available to get this info using the POST ID from FaceBook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I located solution for this myself. This is how I did

```
- (IBAction)likes_count:(id)sender {

    [self requestGraph: @"123456789876543?fields=likes.limit(1000)" sender:^(int count) {

        textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
        likesCount = 0;

    }];

}

-(void)requestGraph: (NSString*) fbRequest sender: (void (^)(int count))callback {

    likes_count.enabled = FALSE;
    FBRequest *like = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:fbRequest];

    [like startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)  {

        if(likesCount == 0)
            likesCount = [result [@"likes"][@"data"]  count];
        else
            likesCount = likesCount + [result [@"data"]  count];


        if (result [@"likes"][@"paging"] [@"next"] != NULL) {

            [self requestGraph:[result [@"likes"][@"paging"] [@"next"] substringFromIndex:27] sender:callback ];
        }
        else if (result [@"paging"] [@"next"]  != NULL)
            [self requestGraph:[result [@"paging"] [@"next"] substringFromIndex:27] sender:callback];

        else {

            callback(likesCount);
            likes_count.enabled = TRUE;
        }

    }]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call a new request with the FB object:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"ID/likes"];
```

Replace `ID` with the Facebook ID of the post you're interested in.  This call will return an array with all like information for that photo.

In the `-facebook requestDidLoad:` method, just get the count of that array to return the number of likes.

`NSInteger likeCount = [result count];`

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you. Thanks for ur help

Comment: Is there a way I can get the ID of all the post from a particular user?

Comment: This is just bringing the count in particular page. Max in a page the json is bringing 25 userID. So always the max count is 25